# How can I change focus between panels in a StackPanel using GAS

Tags: google-apps-script, stackpanel

I have a stackpanel containing 3 panels.
After the user clicks a button on page-1, I want page-2 to become visible.
How can I achieve this?

**Edit-1**

As I thought the question I asked really is a general one, I did not provide code.
But Serge insas and Zig Mandell asked for code, so here it is.

```
function doGet() 
{
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();

  var stackPanel = app.createStackPanel().setSize('100%', '100%'); //Create stack panel

  var onClick =  app.createServerHandler('onClick');
  var button = app.createButton('Button on second panel...').setId('btnPageTwo').addClickHandler(onClick);

  //add widgets to each stack panel, and name the stacked panels
  stackPanel.add(app.createLabel('Text on first panel...'), 'One');
  stackPanel.add(button, 'Two');
  stackPanel.add(app.createLabel('Text on third Panel...'), 'Three');

  app.add(stackPanel); //Add the panel to the application
  return app;
}

function onClick(e)
{
   Logger.log('In onClick --> show stackPanel "Three" now');
}
```

In this example I would like to show panel Two at startup and after clicking the button I would like to show panel 3.

I tried using focusPanels, but that didn't help

```
function doGet() 
{
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();

  var stackPanel = app.createStackPanel().setSize('100%', '100%'); //Create stack panel


  // FocusPanels are limited to contain ONE widget
  var focusOne   = app.createFocusPanel().setId('focusOne');
  var focusTwo   = app.createFocusPanel().setId('focusTwo');
  var focusThree = app.createFocusPanel().setId('focusThree');

  // Create panels to overcome the one-widget-limitation of focuspanels
  var ver = app.createVerticalPanel().setId('ver');
  var hor = app.createHorizontalPanel().setId('hor');
  var tab = app.createTabPanel().setId('tab');
  var tabOne = app.createVerticalPanel().setId('tabOne');
  var tabTwo = app.createHorizontalPanel().setId('tabTwo');
  tab.add(tabOne, 'One').add(tabTwo, 'Two');
  focusOne.add(ver);
  focusTwo.add(hor);
  focusThree.add(tab);

  var labOne = app.createLabel('Text on first panel...');
  var labThree = app.createLabel('Text on second tab of third panel...');
  var onClick = app.createServerHandler('onClick');
  var button = app.createButton('Button on second panel...').setId('btnPageTwo').addClickHandler(onClick);

  ver.add(labOne);
  hor.add(button);
  tabTwo.add(labThree);
  tab.selectTab(1); // Select second tab

  //add widgets to each stack panel, and name the stack panel
  stackPanel.add(focusOne, 'stackOne').add(focusTwo, 'stackTwo').add(focusThree, 'stackThree');

  app.add(stackPanel); //Add the panel to the application
  return app;
}

function onClick(e)
{
   Logger.log('In onClick --> show focusPanel "Three" now');
   var app   = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
   var focusThree  = app.getElementById('focusThree');
   focusThree.setFocus(true);
   return app;
}
```

Comment: could you show a minimal and testable code please ? thx

Comment: Show code using client or server handlers, otherwise will likely be closed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this has been the subject of an [enhancement request](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3488) for quite a while (dec 2012) but I'm afraid Google won't do anything about it since they stopped UiApp development (they recommend switching to HTMLService).

You could eventually use [tabPanel](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/tab-panel) instead, this one has all the necessary features.

[Test here](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwZvBDlGal-eTHx7t_FGth2R0xRTdr0MeIfrzECukjStxlxPYbI/exec)

code below :

```
function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var tabPanel = app.createTabPanel().setSize('100%', '100%').setId('tabP'); //Create tab panel
  var onClick =  app.createServerHandler('onClick');
  var button = app.createButton('Button on second panel...').setId('btnPageTwo').addClickHandler(onClick);
  //add widgets to each tab panel, and name the tabed panels
  tabPanel.add(app.createLabel('Text on first panel...'), 'One');
  tabPanel.add(button, 'Two');
  tabPanel.add(app.createLabel('Text on third Panel...'), 'Three');
  app.add(tabPanel); //Add the panel to the application
  tabPanel.selectTab(1);  
  return app;
}

function onClick(e){
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var tabP = app.getElementById('tabP').selectTab(2);  
  return app;
}
```

Comment: I use a tabpanel in a stackpanel already and also switching tabs in the tabpanel. Anyway, thanks for the response.  Too bad Google switches so often in what they will support (well) in future.  I guess I will have no choice as using a tabPanel for those other stackpanel pages as well